# Is there a way to get the google search redirect url after redirecting?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example,you search something in google.com.You click on a result link,and then you will be redirect to a 'https://www.google.....' then to the right site.How can I get the url ('https://www.google.....') after I come to the right site.

```
document.referrer
```

can't help.It only gives 'https://www.google.com/' while I want to get the full url.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about doing this would probably be to use [`chrome.webRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) to get the old referrer before the redirect.

One way to do it would be like this:

```
var requestIds = [];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
  var temp = {requestId:details.requestId,url:details.url}
  requestIds.push(temp);
},
{urls: ["*://www.google.com/url*"]});
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  requestIds.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    if(parseInt(details.requestId)-parseInt(v.requestId)<=2){
      details.requestHeaders.forEach(function(val,ind,arr){
        if(val.name =="Referer")
          val.value = v.url;
      });
      requestIds.splice(i,1);
    }
  });
},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"],types:["main_frame"]},["requestHeaders","blocking"]);
```

You also need `"webRequest","webRequestBlocking"` for your permissions in your manifest file.

What this does is pluck out the url, then add it onto the request headers of the approximate resulting call. I was originally going to show how during a redirect the `requestId` remains the same, but it is not a conventional redirect. As far as I can see there is no way to correlate the first request with the next other than it will have an id that is very close, hence the `<= 2`. Regardless of what you want to do with it, the first listener will provide you with the url you want, it just might be hard to associate it with the resultant page.

Be aware that while this does change the referrer header, it will not show up in dev tools or as `document.referrer`.